# Replacing huge DataGridViewComboBoxColumn for performance

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I have a dialog with a WinForms *DataGridView* that shows a user list. Each row contains an AD-User combobox (*DataGridViewComboboxColumn*) that can grow very large (10K+ items). 
This DataGridView is used to link the users with their corresponding AD-Users. The content of this combobox does not change between rows.

For performance reasons, I want to change this combobox to something that scales better.

I was thinking about using a TextBox with a small selection button in it. The button then would open a modal dialog for selecting the AD-User. The cell would then contain the selected AD-User object. 
Alternatively this dialog could also open on a cell-doubleclick, but I think that would not be very intuitive.

Would this be the best option for replacing this combobox? If you have other/better ways of handling such a selection, please let me know.

And if so: How can I create such a custom DataGridView-Cell (TextBox + Button)?

Comment: The easiest solution is making the column readonly, then use a button column after that. Then handle `CellContentClick` event of `DataGridView` to detect button clicks.

Comment: Another option is creating a custom column based on `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272385/3110834) with a bit change to shows the value of cell instead of label text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is making the column readonly, then use a button column after that. Then handle `CellContentClick` event of `DataGridView` to detect button clicks.

Another option is creating a custom column based on DataGridViewButtonColumn. Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272385/3110834) with a bit change to shows the value of cell instead of label text.

You can also achieve it without creating any new column type by just custom painting the cell, something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54522223/3110834).

**Example**

My choice is deriving from `DataGridView` button column for better user experience, for example highlighting the button on mouse move. To do so, I'll change this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272385/3110834) which shows how to render a label and a button in a single cell. Here I change it a bit to show cell values as a label text:

[image]

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class DataGridViewLookupColumn : DataGridViewButtonColumn
{
    public DataGridViewLookupColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = new DataGridViewLookupCell();
        ButtonText = "...";
    }
    public string ButtonText { get; set; }
    public override object Clone()
    {
        var c = (DataGridViewLookupColumn)base.Clone();
        c.ButtonText = this.ButtonText;
        return c;
    }
}
public class DataGridViewLookupCell : DataGridViewButtonCell
{
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds,
        Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex,
        DataGridViewElementStates elementState,
        object value, object formattedValue, string errorText,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        var g = this.DataGridView;
        var c = (DataGridViewLookupColumn)this.OwningColumn;
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState,
            value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle,
            DataGridViewPaintParts.All &
            ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground &
            ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
        var cellRectangle = g.GetCellDisplayRectangle(c.Index, rowIndex, false);
        var buttonRectangle = GetContentBounds(rowIndex);
        var textRectangle = new Rectangle(cellRectangle.Location,
            new Size(cellRectangle.Width - GetButtonWidth(),
            cellRectangle.Height));
        buttonRectangle.Offset(cellRectangle.Location);
        var alignment = cellStyle.Alignment;
        cellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, buttonRectangle, rowIndex, elementState,
            value, c.ButtonText, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle,
            DataGridViewPaintParts.All &
            ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
        cellStyle.Alignment = alignment;
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, textRectangle, rowIndex, elementState,
             value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle,
             DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
    }
    protected override Rectangle GetContentBounds(Graphics graphics,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, int rowIndex)
    {
        var w = GetButtonWidth();
        var r = base.GetContentBounds(graphics, cellStyle, rowIndex);
        return new Rectangle(r.Right - w, r.Top, w, r.Height);
    }
    private int GetButtonWidth()
    {
        var c = (DataGridViewLookupColumn)this.OwningColumn;
        var text = c.ButtonText;
        return TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, c.DefaultCellStyle.Font).Width
            + 10 /*a bit padding */;
    }
}
```

**Handle click on button**

To handle the click on the button, handle `CellContentClick` like a normal `DataGridViewColumnButton` and check if `e.RowIndex > -1` and `e.ColumnIndex ==  your desired column index`:

```
void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //if click is on row header or column header, do nothing.
    if(e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;

    //Check if click is on specific column 
    if( e.ColumnIndex  == dataGridView1.Columns["specific column name"].Index)
    {
        //Put some logic here, for example show a dialog and use result.
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I handle the button click event in this case?

Comment: Like a normal `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, handle `CellContentClick`, check if `e.RowIndex>-1` and `e.ColumnIndex == your desired column index`.

Comment: Thank you!. Would a click on the label text not count as a CellContentClick here?

Comment: Click on label will not raise `CellContentClick`, because we override `GetContentBounds` and returned just the button bound.

Comment: This is very useful. I will mark it as the answer. I think you have a small mistake: The text rectangle width is cellRectangle.Width - ButtonWidth(), I think?

Comment: Do you see the possibility of setting the CellContentClick-Event per column? I want to be able to add the event handler in my own DataGrid.AddColumn method if that is possible.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it and changed the rendering a bit.

Comment: In the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272385/3110834), you see that I've override `OnContentClick`. You can think of using that method. Let's keep this thread dedicated to this column type with standard behaviors. If you have something in mind about adding `CellContentClick` event handler to the column, please ask new question.

Comment: Feel free to notify me if you asked a new question.

Comment: I asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119361/how-to-add-a-cellcontentclick-event-per-column-in-a-datagridview)