# Prepending expand/collapse icon to text on a Datagridview winforms cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I use a Winforms Datagridview to display hierarchical data, inserting indented rows of a deeper level when the user double-clicks a parent row.
Subsequent levels are indented, so expand/collapse icons on a specific column is not an option.
My current solution is to display a boring plus or minus character before the text.
Is there a way to prepend a symbol font at the begining of the indented cell text?

Comment: Add a bit of padding to the first cell based on the required indent, then draw the plus/minus image on the cell in [CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54522223/3110834) for example.

Comment: You may also want to search for a tree gridview or tree listview, a commercial or open source one.